# How do I get the latest version of a framework with cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I get the latest version of a framework with cocoapods?

I can see that I have a framework installed, but I don't know if I have the latest version.  I'd like to tell cocoapods to install the latest version of this specific framework. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory and `pod update`

Comment: Also, if you have hardcoded versions of pods, you should check the availability of updates directly at http://cocoapods.org/ or at the project home site

Comment: How does that not answer the question?